# Remove zero rows from a list of list in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of list in Scala such as:

```
val lst = List(List(60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(47, 0, 1, 1, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

and I want to remove all zero rows and the result should be like:

```
List(List(60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0), List(47, 0, 1, 1, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Does Scala list have any built-in method to remove these rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to keep only items (lists) matching a predicate; The predicate can use `exists` to check for non-zero elements:

```
lst.filter(_.exists(_ != 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more related question: How can I remove rows with at least one negative value like -1? I tried lst.filter(_.exists(_ == -1)) but it returns all rows with -1 as one of the elements.

Comment: "at least one negative value" would translate to `exists(_ < 0)`, and you want to _remove_ those, so you need the opposite: `lst.filter(_.forall(_ >=  0))`, right?

Answer (score 2):

@Tzach Zohar answer is perfectly fine but here is another way to approach it.

```
scala> lst.filterNot(xs => xs.forall(_ == 0))
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(
  List(60, 0, 1, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  List(47, 0, 1, 1, 2, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```